# How can we allow our app to run when screen is locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a problem with device locking. If my app is running and device gets locked then my app is also not working. I want my app to work even if my device is locked.
My code is as follows:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];

 background = YES;

 UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

 bgTask  = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
  [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
  bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
 }];

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
  if (background) {
   StressFreeAlarmViewController *alarmController=[[StressFreeAlarmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StressFreeAlarmViewController" bundle:nil];

   [alarmController setTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updatingApp) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];

   background=NO;
  }
 });

}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
 // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 background = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment this line

```
 [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
 bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;


here


 UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

 bgTask  = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
  //[app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
  //bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

When device is locked, you can't install app. But when app is already in device, you can prevent locking thru preventSleepTimer framework as in above post

When device is locked, Error message will be : error: failed to launch '/Users/venkateswarlun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-celefkdlufzfpexcvbngfwhpwosr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XXXXXX.app/XXXXXX' -- device locked

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to prevent the screen lock for that here following code is use

```
- (void)startPreventSleep {
    // We need to play a sound at least every 10 seconds to keep the iPhone awake.
    // We create a new repeating timer, that begins firing now and then every ten seconds.
    // Every time it fires, it calls -playPreventSleepSound
    self.preventSleepTimer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]
                                                  interval:10.0
                                                target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(playPreventSleepSound)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES];
    // We add this timer to the current run loop
    NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:self.preventSleepTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

stopPreventSleep stops the sleep preventing.

```
- (void)stopPreventSleep {
    [self.preventSleepTimer invalidate];
    self.preventSleepTimer = nil;
}
```

[For More detail You can refer the Link Here.](http://blog.marcopeluso.com/2009/08/23/how-to-prevent-iphone-from-deep-sleeping/)