# How to prevent auto-lock screen in hooking SpringBoard?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

My application needs the screen be unlocked to do some functions, usually this app runs as background process, how can I prevent auto-lock? I mean on jailbroken environment.

Why does the code below can not be available from SpringBoard?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

Comment: I mean even when my app is changed to background.

Comment: yes, just add this line in your AppDelegate.m file in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: Sorry, after testing it doesn't works,... but maybe this can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12141634/how-can-we-allow-our-app-to-run-when-screen-is-locked

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on `SpringBoard` class

This code should be run in SpringBoard:

```
SpringBoard *sb = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[sb clearIdleTimer];
```

After you get things done, remember to reset it to normal state:

```
[sb resetIdleTimerAndUndim:YES]; // or NO if you don't want the screen dims at once.
```

Comment: Why does this can not be available in SpringBoard?

Comment: This is not a public API and you have to add the header yourself. As for setIdleTimerDisabled, what I can only say is that SpringBoard is designed this way.

Comment: I have added the headers of SpringBoard to my project but no use.

Comment: This code has to be run in SpringBoard. If you call the method in other apps, it wont work

Comment: Yes, I call it in SpringBoard, I can't find out why doesn't work.